# C++ builder Alexandria 11.3 patch failed

Tags: c++builder-11-alexandria

Whenever I try to install the 11.3 patch for C++Builder, I get an error.

[image: C++ Builder error]

Can anyone help me?

I tried re-installing C++Builder completely, then I tried a number of times to install the patch without anything else running, but no luck.

Comment: You should contact Embarcadero Support directly